# The locale to use to show error messages in TypeScript in Czech in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

This works in terminal: tsc --locale "cs"
error TS2322: Typ 6 nejde přiřadit typu string.

But not directly in VS Code:
Value "cs" is not accepted in "typescript.locale": "cs" in settings.json.
It is possible to solve this problem and have czech error messages directly in my code?

Comment: TypeScript's `cs` language pack is in `node_modules/typescript/`. Unfortunately, it isn't available as a VS Code language pack. It might, though, be a good starting point for adding one to the VS Code marketplace.